# Integral of a complex number showing 1=2?

Tags: proof-verification

$$\int z \,dz=\dfrac{z^2}{2}$$
$$z=a+bi\implies \int (a+bi) \,dz=\int z \, dz$$
$$a(a+bi)+bi(a+bi)=(a+bi)^2=\dfrac{z^2}{2}=\dfrac{(a+bi)^2}{2}$$
$$ 2(a+bi)^2=(a+bi)^2$$
Assume $z \neq 0$:
$$1=2$$
Where is the fallacy?

Comment: $2(a+bi)^2\not=(a+bi)^2$, I believe...

Comment: Where are you getting your third line from?

Comment: How did you conclude that $a(a+bi)+bi(a+bi)$ has something to do with evaluating the integrals?

Comment: Evaluating the first one gives a(z)+bi(z), substituting z=(a+bi) gives that line.

Comment: @MathNoob: You are treating $z$ as constant and not constant simultaneously.

Comment: The first line is wrong to begin with. You have omitted the arbitrary additive constant. Then the conclusion in the second line is wrong. You can't replace a dummy variable with a constant because then there is nothing to integrate; that's likely the error you are looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your third line you write $z^2=\displaystyle\frac{z^2}2$ out of the blue.  This only happens when $z=0$, so you cannot conclude that $1=2$.

Ok, now I got what you were trying to do. When you "evaluate the integrals" you are taking $a$ and $b$ as constants. That makes no sense if $a+ib=z$ and $z$ is your integration variable.

More concretely, $$a=\frac{z+\bar z}2,\ b=\frac{z-\bar z}{2i}.$$. You cannot treat them as constants.

Comment: Evaluating the integral $\int (a+bi) dz$ gives $a(z)+bi(z)=z(a+bi)=z^2$ Evaluating the second gives z^2/2.

Comment: No it doesn't. If $a$ and $b$ do not depend on $z$, then you cannot write $z=a+ib$.